# Поиск пробелов вне кавычек

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте.

Как в C# с помощью Regex найти лишние пробелы (больше одного) вне кавычек?

К примеру, есть текст: `Какой    то  "Текст   с пробелами" и  кавычками.`

Должно быть на выходе: `Какой то "Текст   с пробелами" и кавычками.`

Знаю лишь, что формула `("([^"]+)")` ищет текст в кавычках, а `(\ +)` - лишние пробелы. Но мне не удается 'инвертировать' первую формулу.

Comment: А такой текст: `начало "вот \" вложенная кавычка" конец` как должен обрабатываться?

Comment: Такое исключено.

Comment: А если кавычка не сбалансированна? `1   "     1` ?

Answer (score 2):

http://ideone.com/DDcTH0

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"(""[^""]*"")|([^ ""]+)|( )+", @"$1$2$3")
// JS: text.replace(/("[^"]*")|([^ "]+)|( )+/g, "$1$2$3")
```

Comment: Интересный вариант, спасибо=)

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            const string text = "Какой то  \"Текст   с пробелами\" и   кавычками. И   еще   немного    \"Текста    \" с   кавычками     и \"  без?  \"    !";
            var newText = Regex.Replace(text, "(?<=^[^\"]*(\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*?)*)\\s{2,}", " ");
            Console.WriteLine(newText);
        }
    }
}
```